# in-database logging utility for BC outside the main database transaction

Tags: multithreading, logging, transactions, saas, dynamics-business-central

I'm using latest Business Central SAAS 23, trying to add in-database tracing for some long running processes. (I can definitely do something via outbound HTTP, but it'd be more convenient and probably faster if the traces were rows in a custom BC table).

The issue I'm having is that I can't isolate the database transaction for the logging from whatever implicit transaction is underway in the main extension code. I'd like to be able to simply insert debug/trace records as the code progresses, but have those records remain if the calling procedure's transaction is rolled back because of some database transaction error (primary key, can't obtain lock, etc).

I've tried:

- Different code units for the main/logger code
- Different extensions for the main/logger code
- Pub/Sub (event triggered from calling code) with a single session
- StartSession + Pub/Sub to run the handler in another session

If this tracing approach doesn't work out I guess I can just buffer the log lines in memory until the next Commit and then write them out, but again that's fairly inconvenient.

Is it actually possible to maintain a separated database transaction for e.g. logging?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not supported. Would telemetry help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/telemetry-overview?

Comment: I'm not sure @ChristianBraeunlich - I'd need to be able to log arbitrary text (with no reformatting) and later query it by timestamp range.

Comment: @ChristianBraeunlich I did see that telemetry can do arbitrary logging, but then extra tooling is needed to make use of those logs.  I also found that you can actually have a different transaction in a 2nd session via StartSession -- apparently I was doing it incorrectly in my prior experiments. Verified on BC SAAS 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this article "Out-of-transaction database writes" that does exactly what I was looking for. https://vjeko.com/2015/11/20/out-of-transaction-database-writes/

Seems it *does* work with a 2nd session, so I'm not sure what I was doing wrong with my prior attempts.

The attached link contains code that spawns a session for each call to the logging function (which is possibly a bit slow); that could be improved with some coordination from the calling code.